# Interpreting Javascript code using only a server-side script (no browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

I am currently looking to interpret Javascript code using only a server-side script (no browser). Specifically, I would like to load and use external scripts as if the server script were a browser, storing the evaluated results to a log file. It appears that something like node.js or another similar server-side Javascript library would be able to assist me in doing so. Any recommendations or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "as if the server script were a browser," do you mean that you want to have a DOM accessible?

Comment: Exactly, in addition to having the properties and methods of objects such as `window` and `document` available as well.

Comment: `window` and `document` are part of the DOM.

Comment: I was under the impression that `window` was more of a browser-specific addition to the DOM. Either way, having the DOM accessible is a must. I just tested https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer, which embeds the V8 Javascript interpreter into Ruby, and it appears that neither `document` nor `window` are available as objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need a DOM, Rhino, NodeJS, or V8 *alone* will not suffice. [Envjs](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides) bridges the DOM gap.

> The goal of Envjs is to provide a highly portable javascript implementation of the Browser as a scripting environment ( often referred to as a 'headless' browser ).
>
> The default implementation is Rhino but many developers have and continue to develop bridges for running Envjs in Ruby, Python, and other host languages with the SpiderMonkey and V8 javascript engines, to name a few.

[Source](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides)

See also: [*Bringing the browser to the server*](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks! I found a Ruby implementation of this as well (https://github.com/smparkes/env-js).

Answer (score 1):

You should try jsdom (available as node module), or go all-in with [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/), a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) is a very good one.

You can interact with it in your programs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server environment you can host Google's V8 JS engine: http://code.google.com/p/v8/

Host JS in C#:
http://west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/10688.aspx

etc..